# Float value comparison bug

Tags: php

```
$x = array(
    "0",
    "1689.60",
    "0.00",
    "-200",
    "432.00",
    "33.60"
);

$v = 0;

foreach($x as $p) {
    $v += $p;
}

if($v == 1955.2) {
    echo 'equal';
}
```

with this simple script I assumed that it will output "equal" but it didn't.

If I changed the value of -200 to -100 and changed the expected result value to 2055.2, it works just fine. I already solved my problem by type casting $v to string but I just want to find out why it didn't work if it's a numeric(integer or float) type.

Comment: Did you happen to echo the value of v as an integer after you summed the numbers for bug checking?  Could you tell me what the result was if you did?

Comment: Yes, the value of v is 1955.2 and upon var_dump the type is float. value and type are the same but it return false on the conditional statement. tried it on 5.3 and 5.5 php version.

Comment: Using your example, try this if check and tell me if it echoes 'equal'

`if ($v - 1955.2 <= 0.001) { echo 'equal'; }`

Comment: Refer to the source in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

The problem here is your floating values, even though they appear very equal, are not due to how PHP (and the computer itself) represents floating point integers.  There are a few solutions in the comments on the source to testing floats for equality.  I highly recommend going through that source; it's brief and informative.